# Django Rest Framework как вывести конкретные поля модели

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework как вывести конкретные поля модели, по разным урлам выводить разные поля, например вывести только id и title

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import Ticket
from .serializers import TicketSerializer

@csrf_exempt
def ticket_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        tickets = Ticket.objects.all() #так выводит все поля
        tickets1 = Ticket.objects.values('title') # тут хочу вывести конкктеное поле title например
        serializer = TicketSerializer(tickets, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = TicketSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Ticket, username, ticket_author_name 


class TicketSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    ticket_author = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default=ticket_author_name)
    assigned_users = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default=username)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    status = serializers.CharField()
    priority = serializers.CharField()
    progress = serializers.CharField()
    tracker = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Ticket.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.ticket_author = validated_data.get('ticket_author', instance.ticket_author)
        instance.assigned_users = validated_data.get('assigned_users', instance.assigned_users)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        instance.priority = validated_data.get('priority', instance.priority)
        instance.progress = validated_data.get('progress', instance.progress)
        instance.tracker = validated_data.get('tracker', instance.tracker)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime  # for init our current date
from .vars import ticket_status, ticket_priority, ticket_progress, ticket_tracker


username = 'Alex'
ticket_author_name = "Roman"


def form_ticket_statuses():
    return ((k, v) for (k, v) in ticket_status.items())


def form_ticket_priority():
    return ((k, v) for (k, v) in ticket_priority.items())


def form_ticket_progress():
return ((k, v) for (k, v) in ticket_progress.items())

def form_ticket_tracker():
    return ((k, v) for (k, v) in ticket_tracker.items())

def now_date():
#    return int(datetime.now().timestamp())
    return datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()


class Ticket(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    ticket_author = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=ticket_author_name)
    assigned_users = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=username)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Create your title')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='Create your description')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=form_ticket_statuses(), default='New')
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=form_ticket_priority(), default='Normal')
    progress = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=form_ticket_progress(), default='0%')
    tracker = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=form_ticket_tracker(), default='Task')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

выдает ошибку KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `status` on serializer `TicketSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'status'."

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте туда модель и сериализатор

Comment: Исправил , добавил

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что отсутствует значение для поля `status`, потому что в сериализаторе это поле перечислено, а в кверисете его нет.

Для решения вопроса вам необходимо создать ещё сериализатор, в котором вы укажите какие именно поля необходимо обрабатывать, и лучше использовать [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) и [ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). Приведу пример использования:

serializer

```
class TicketSerializerIdAndTitleField(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('id', 'title')


class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'
```

view

```
class TicketListIdAndTitleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializerIdAndTitleField


class TicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
```

В вашем же случае, можно сделать примерно так:

```
@csrf_exempt
def ticket_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        tickets = Ticket.objects.all() #так выводит все поля
        tickets1 = Ticket.objects.all() 
        serializer = TicketSerializerIdAndTitleField(tickets, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = TicketSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: спасибо, добавил отдельные сериалайзеры на каждое отображение всё работает